# Export ply. with Noise texture

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, export

Disclaimer: this is my first question on stackExch. so quite new in Blender also.

I wanted to add a noise on my torus, which I could do on the Shading/Add-> NoiseTexture. It was visible in object mode and edit mode. As soon as I export it, I only see the torus without the noise. Have also called several websites, but could not find a solution. Need it for my thesis work.
Thanks to all in advance

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Make sure you always take a moment to search the web or Blender StackExchange to see if a question similar to yours has already been asked. If you still find it impossible to solve the problem then ask a new question.